# Word for "completing quickly to a very high standard"

Tags: single-word-requests

What's a word that means, to complete something totally, to extremely high quality, in an impressively short amount of time.

> After ____ the project, ...

> He ____ his assignment.

I thought of "blitzing through" but it is quite informal, and the multifaceted meaning is not necessarily obvious. "Smashing" is another informal word that almost works.

I would prefer answers that can be used in reasonably formal writing, but if there is something close to unambiguously capturing all the meanings I want to convey, and it turns out to sit on the informal side, that would still be the best answer.

Comment: Please edit to indicate what level of informality is acceptable. "Acing" is a step up from "smashing," but still less than formal. (I'd say "blitzing through" might actually suggest a rushed, sloppy job...)

Comment: [***expensive***](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/8600348-jim-jarmusch-once-told-me-fast-cheap-and-good-pick).

Comment: Generally speaking, any allusion to ***rapidly*** completing some assigned task will tend to imply ***hasty, slapdash, careless,...*** But maybe that implication is weaker or not present at all with *He [soon] **polished off** that awkward job I assigned him last week*.

Comment: Informally: *After **nailing** the project... / He **nailed** his assignment.* [to perform or complete perfectly or impressively](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nail)

Comment: Flying through.  I think this includes both the speed and the high standard.  (High flyer, high flying.)

Answer (score 1):

He *blazed through* his project

---

[Merriam/Webster]

> Definition of blaze (Entry 2 of 5) intransitive verb
>
> 1a: to burn brightly the sun blazed overhead b: to flare up : FLAME
> inflation blazed up 2: to be conspicuously brilliant or resplendent
> fields blazing with flowers 3: to shoot rapidly and repeatedly
> —usually used with away 4: to proceed extremely rapidly : BLAST

Answer (score 0):

> After **excelling** in the project, ...
>
> He **excelled** in his assignment.

**excel** (v.)

> To be superior or preëminent in the possession of some quality, or in
> the performance of some action, usually in a good sense; to surpass
> others. Const. *in*, sometimes *at*. OED

> If someone excels in something or excels at it, they are very good at
> doing it. [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/excel)

> If you excel at math, you are doing it better than anyone else.
> [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/excel)

---

> He **excelled** in the assignment and impressed Foust, who
> subsequently assigned him to be the executive officer of Charlie
> Company of the battalion. [Darrel Whitcomb; *Call Sign "Dustoff"*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Call_Sign_Dustoff/GqQfGrekIeAC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22excelled%20in%20the%20assignment%22&pg=PA97&printsec=frontcover)

> EXPERIENCE—Was recruited by this former employer in 1997, and then
> **excelled** in the following track record of accomplishment in both the sales and production management areas;  [Anne McKinney;
> *Real-Resumes for Sales*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Real_resumes_for_Sales/FuVjV6QE4_IC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22excelled%22%20deadline&pg=PA135&printsec=frontcover)

*Excel* can refer to any number of parameters, but can convey an "extremely high quality". Others, like speed and efficiency may need to be intuited. On the other hand, a verb that describes the speed of completion may leave the quality of the work in question. If it has to be a single word, you may need to opt for one or the other, otherwise "excels in quality and speed" works.

Comment: I'm not sure that "excel" works as it refers only to the quality, not the speed.

Comment: @Greybeard I've added a note about a possible tradeoff. I don't think the OED definition is that limiting, however. You can excel in quality, speed, efficiency, etc. By itself, *excel* leaves open these possibilities. However, I agree that speed isn't explicit.

Answer (score -1):

**breeze**

> To progress swiftly or easily

*We breezed through the test.*

[American Heritage Dictionary]

Comment: It's too insensitive, as if no care is being taken. But the word I'm looking for should imply the exact opposite, that every care was taken and the result and process cannot be faulted and only praised.

Comment: @theonlygusti I've added to my answer. Please check to see if this one works.

Comment: Yes breeze works very well

Comment: I like *breeze through* but *bulldoze* feels all wrong.